# How does WHERE NOT EXISTS in this query work?

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, relational-database

I have 3 tables one for doctor, patient and Appointments as follow

```
create table Doctors 
(
    Did int identity primary key,
    docName varchar (20),
    specialization varchar (20),
    salary decimal (8,2)
)

create table Patients
(
    Pid int identity primary key,
    fullName varchar (20)
)

create table Appointments
(
    datey DATETIME,
    pid int foreign key REFERENCES Patients(Pid),
    did int foreign key REFERENCES Doctors(Did),
    primary key (pid, did)
)
```

and I'm trying to understand a query that "Get doctors that have had appointments with all patients". Here is query:

```
SELECT D.docName
FROM Doctors D
WHERE NOT EXISTS (
    (
        SELECT P.Pid
        FROM Patients P
    )
    EXCEPT
    (
        SELECT A.pid
        FROM Appointments A
        WHERE A.did = D.Did
    )
)
```

I understand that the subquery part after `Where not Exists` is querying for All the patients that don't currently have doctor appointments. What I fail to understand is how when this is given to `where NOT Exists`, it shows me the names of the doctors that do have appointments since when I ran the sub-query with some data in visual studio code. The result of the query is empty.

So how exactly does the `where not exist` and generally the query works in this case?

Thanks.

Comment: Generally more common to write this as two nested `NOT EXISTS`, the effect (and query plan) is the same, but might be easier to read

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a little complicated to explain.  But the idea is to rephrase the questions:

> Get all doctors such that there is no patient that doesn't have an appointment with the doctor.

Even if English is your native language, all those negatives make the question hard to follow.  It is another way of saying what you want:  "Get doctors that have had appointments with all patients".

Here are the steps:

- The first subquery gets all patients.
- The second subquery gets all patients for a particular doctor.
- The `EXCEPT` gets the list of patients that have not had an appointment with the doctor.
- Finally, if there are none, then the doctor has had appointments with all patients.

An alternative approach using aggregation seems self-explanatory by contrast:

```
SELECT D.did, D.docName
FROM Doctors D JOIN
     Appointments A
     ON A.did = D.did
GROUP BY D.did, D.docName
HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT A.pid) = (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM Patients);
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. I understand it now. The aggregation approach is a much better approach to this as you have mentioned.

Comment: Self-explanatory but not necessarily faster. Double `NOT EXISTS` is a common approach to relational division